# Constrained optimization with alternates in special conditions

Tags: optimization, notation, matlab, constraint-programming

I have the following optimization problem.

$$\max_{a b} acx+bdy+z \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

subjected to

$$ c = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } 2xa-yb-z\geq 4\\
0, & \text{if} \ 2ax<yb+z\\
\frac{2xa-yb-z}{4},& \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}  $$

$$ d = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } xc-yb-z\geq 2\\
0, & \text{if} \ xc<yb+z\\
\frac{xc-yb-z}{2},& \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}  $$

$$ 0\leq a \leq1 \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$ 0\leq b \leq1 \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

I'm using matlab to optimize  $a$ and $b$ using **fmincon** function. I can define $a$ and $b$ as bound constraints but I'm confused where should I define the function $c$.

Thanks in advance for any help and/or clue.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the same problem after getting no response here and I received response there. In case somebody else is also looking for the answer please follow [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/263478-constraint-optimization-with-alternatives-under-specific-conditions).